# CXF service and getport takes a lot of time

Tags: soap, cxf

I am developing a SOAP client with CXF.
I have the code generated by wsdl2java.
I have done a JAR executable to test.
When I try to make a request, I do this first:

```
Service ss = Service.create(wsdlURL, SERVICE_NAME);
 MiNTService port = ss.getPort(MiNTServiceSOAP, MiNTService.class);
```

- wsdl is the URL to the web service.
- SERVICE_NAME is a QName of the service.
- MiNTService is the class generated from wsdl2java code.
- MiNTServiceSOAP is a QName of the endpoint
- MintSErvice.class is the name of the class generated by wsld2java

The service.create expends 10 minutes
The gerPort() expends 10 minutes too.
And after all that time... the request is done.

I have try put all wsdl locally, but the same result.
What could be happening????.

The system has:

- 4GB RAM
- 5GB free space disk.
- CPU 2.5 GHz
- Ping to the server is normal...
- The connection is over https
- With Axis2 there is no problem of time request, but we cant use axis2 because has a lot of problems with signed request... and we are trying CXF.

Thanks to all

Comment: Without knowing your exact setup (cpu, ram, network topology) and more code it's hard to guess what consumes that lot of time. I know that the first call to a service can take some time on the server to initialize everything but 10 minutes are weird.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:
The problem was the way to export a "runnable jar file" from Eclipse.

If you package the libraies into the jar... it becomes slow.

The solution is select the option of "Copy required libraries into a sub-folder next to the generated jar" in the export process.

Tremendo el asunto.....

Bye

Answer (score 0):

I am also having the same problem of direct calling below Service constructor when the provided **web service is down**. Service.create(wsdlURL, SERVICE_NAME) also internally calls below constructor.

In my case, When the web service is online everything works fine.
What I expect is a quick response from the Service initialization if it is not possible to initialize without hanging long time.

- Can we set a timeout to this call?
- Are there any specific way of doing this?
- Or is this a known problem of CXF?

here is the Service Constructor I am using:

```
 protected Service(java.net.URL wsdlDocumentLocation, QName serviceName) {
        delegate = Provider.provider().createServiceDelegate(wsdlDocumentLocation,
            serviceName,
            this.getClass());
 }
```

Comment: This isn't an answer but another question based on the original post.  Consider posting your own question.